# In WPF, is it possible for the XAML to obtain the color of the currently rendered background?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a control that displays a progress bar.

I want the color of the progress bar to effectively be a stronger version of the currently rendered background color, e.g.:

- If the background is light yellow, I want the progress bar to be a strong yellow.
- If the background is light green, I want the progress bar to be a strong green.
- etc.

Is this possible in WPF?

Note that I have no idea who is setting the background color for me, so I can't really set it manually.

**Update**

I should clarify that some of the parent controls set the `Background` to `transparent` in the XAML.

However, as far as the visual tree goes, this simply means that the `Background` gets passed down to all of the children.

Comment: Can't you just bind to the current control template background?

Comment: What about adding an attached property that walks thru the VisualTree to get the parent's background?

Comment: Try using backgroud of parent window 

((Window)this.Parent).Background

Comment: Are you trying to implement *themes*? With this approach (having different styles/brushes/etc.) you do not do anything in the view or ViewModel (mvvm?), but it's done automatically via using same key for the style, but merging a different `ResourceDisctionary`.

Comment: @Simplyvaibh Thanks for the tip, but I am using MVVM so am avoiding using code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what type of control sets background bind to it using *RelativeSource*. Then based on retrieved Brush adjusts it to your demands.

**First approach using Converter as follows:**

```
 class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         var background = value as SolidColorBrush;
         if (background.Color == Colors.LightYellow) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
         if (background.Color == Colors.LightGreen) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
         return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ProgressBar Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Background,
      Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"/>
```

**or latter approach only using XAML:**

```
<ProgressBar>
    <ProgressBar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Background}" Value="LightYellow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Background}" Value="LightGreen">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ProgressBar.Style>
</ProgressBar>
```

Comment: That's not all. With this binding the background of the `ProgreeBar` will have the same color as the background. I think he would need to provide a converter woo, where he adjusts the color based on the rendered background color

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answwer, this worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use progress bar in common style as follows and bind the foreground color in the appropriate ViewModel.
vm:ProgressBar is a usercontrol

```
 <vm:ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                        Width="140"
                                        Height="120"
                                        Margin="12"
                                        Panel.ZIndex="5"
                                        Padding="10"
                                       DataContext.ProgressBarVisibility,
                                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window,
                                                                                            AncestorLevel=1}}"
                                        d:DesignerVisibility="False">
                            <vm:ProgressBar.Foreground>
                                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" GradientOrigin="0.4,0.4" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding Path=FColor}" />
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </vm:ProgressBar.Foreground>
                        </vm:ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I particularly liked learning that it's possible to use `d:DesignerVisibility="False"`.